# Android Lolipop broke my enyrpted nexus 7 (2012)

Tags: updates, nexus-7, encryption, bootloader, 5.0-lollipop

I just received the update and now my device does not boot any more.
I comes to the point where I have to enter my encryption password. 
The first  time it did this it said:  “Unfortunately your password is correct but your data is corrupted, would you like to do a factory reset” I did not want to do this and powered the device off.
Is there any chance to recover some of the data, before wiping?  I figured out to come up with the bootloader by pressing down power button and both volume keys, but did not get further from there.
Perfect would be some kind of USB mass storage mode while connected to a computer. 
Please help

I wished this lolipop update would never have poped up!

Comment: You need to clear the cache and dalvik-cache.

Comment: Worked! It boots now, which took forever during the fist time

Comment: I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing updates, be it from OTA or flashing, you will need to wipe/clean the cache and dalvik-cache (They retain information that could cause problems as well as bootloops.) Just remember to leave system, data, and other partitions alone.